# How to find numpy array index with condition on inner most values

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a reinforcement learning problem and I'm using Q-Table.

My Q-table has a shape of `(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 2)`, where the state is
`(20, 20, 20)`, actions `(20, 20)` and reward `(2)`.

I'm having trouble finding the action index of the maximum reward prioritized with the first value and then the second.

To explain the last part of the line, here is a small example:

```
...
[[ 2, 3],
 [ 2, 5]
 [ 1, 4]]
...
```

The prioritized value should be `[2, 5]` and the desired output would be the index: `1`.

Just to summarize: input is shaped `(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 2)` NumPy array. Sort Filter by the last two dimensions (the two reward values). Firstly, max values of the first column, and then of those, pick max values of the second column.

The output should be the index of the highest-valued action.

Comment: Can you provide a better example for your use case? You said the array is shaped `(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 2)`, yet in your current example, the element has one of its dimensions equal to `3`... Futhermore, what would be the final output: an array of two elements (the prioritized value) or an array containing prioritized values *for each state*, i.e. shaped `(20, 20, 20, 2)`?

Comment: It's hard to provide a real example since it's so large. 
Output should be shaped (2,), so just a tuple of two numbers, so I can use it as an index for my actions array with shape (20,20).

Q-Table is (20,20,20,20,20,2)
Actions (20,20)

Goal is to find a single action, where the values are prioritized. There could be multiple actions with same values, but then only one would be taken

Comment: In every state (20,20,20), there are (20,20) actions possible. Each of those actions have two rewards (2). I'm looking for the action that the highest first value and out of those the highest second value. So think of it of both columns sorted descending and picking the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort your array based on multiple columns with [`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html?highlight=lexsort#numpy.lexsort). On the documentation page, the example given is the following:

```
>>> a = [1, 5, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4] # First column
>>> b = [9, 4, 0, 4, 0, 2, 1] # Second column
>>> np.lexsort((b,a)) # Sort by a, then by b
array([2, 0, 4, 6, 5, 3, 1])
```

In your case, you want to sort by the first column, then by the second. This means we first need to transpose and then flip the array:

```
>>> x
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 5],
       [1, 6],
       [1, 4]])

>>> np.flip(x.T, 0)
array([[3, 5, 6, 4],
       [2, 2, 1, 1]])
```

Since you want to sort in descending order, we need to take the opposite array (*i.e.* `np.flip(-x.T, axis=0)`). Then apply `np.lexsort`:

```
>>> np.lexsort(np.flip(-x.T, 0), 0)
array([1, 2, 0, 3])
```

The resulting best option is at index `1`, *i.e.* `[2, 5]`.

---

When working with a multi-dimensional array, you could start by reshaping your array into `(20**6, 2)` then apply the above method. Something like this, this consider `x` as a 6-dimensional array

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 100, (20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 2))
>>> x.shape
(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 2)
```

Then:

```
>>> flat = x.reshape(-1, 2)
>>> sort = np.lexsort(np.flip(flat.T, 0), 0)
```

Then `sort[-1]` will return the index of the highest action valued by 1st and 2nd column (*flattened*):

```
>>> sort[-1], flat[sort[-1]]
8086, array([99, 99])
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be exactly what I need. Gonna test it out to be sure. Yeah, I needed an index.

Comment: For my case, I needed to "cast" the index back to (20,20) shape using: action_idx = np.unravel_index(idx, shape=(20,20)).

Otherwise, seems to be working great, so thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, I will. One more question, is it possible to sort the 1st by highest and the 2nd by lowest?

Comment: You could take the opposite of the second column and sort with the above method. Something like `x[..., 1] *= -1` (*keep in mind this will affect your array, since the operation is inplace*)

Comment: That's smart :)) Thanks